# Intento crear un filtro de categorias con Spinner

Tags: java, android

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que funciona como guía de ciudad. La misma toma los datos de una base de datos MySql, viene dividido por categorías de cada cosa.

Pero yo quería intentar hacerlo además por zonas. No se si se entiende. sería como aplicarle un doble filtro.

Agregué un `Spinner al toolbar` para que seleccionen la zona y después puedan seleccionar la categoría que deseen.

Pero la verdad que no se me ocurré como hacerlo! jaja, la única forma que pensé es crear otra categoría que se llame Zona Norte por ejemplo y los locales de esa zona ponerlos en su respectiva categoría y en Zona Norte aparece en los dos.

Entonces desde el spinner seleccionar la zona norte y que aparezcan los locales. pero obviamente cuando selecciona una categoría en especial me van a aparecer todos. :s Alguien podria ayudarme¡? este es mi **ActivityMain.java**

```
package copparoni.rosarioteviste;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;

import copparoni.rosarioteviste.data.AppConfig;
import copparoni.rosarioteviste.data.DatabaseHandler;
import copparoni.rosarioteviste.data.SharedPref;
import copparoni.rosarioteviste.fragment.FragmentCategory;
import copparoni.rosarioteviste.utils.Tools;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

 Spinner zonas;
 String[] datos = {"Zona Norte","Zona Sur","Zona Centro","Zona Este"};

    //for ads
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    private ImageLoader imgloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public ActionBar actionBar;
    public Toolbar toolbar;
    private int cat[];
    private Toolbar toolbar2=null;
    private String[] category=null;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private MenuItem searchItem;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private SharedPref sharedPref;
    private RelativeLayout nav_header_lyt;
    public Fragment fragment = null;
    public Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    static ActivityMain activityMain;





    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        category = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.category, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner navigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        navigationSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        toolbar.addView(navigationSpinner, 0);
        navigationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 1:

                                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this,
                                "you selected: " + cat[18],
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });





if(!imgloader.isInited()) Tools.initImageLoader(this);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);

        prepareAds();
        initToolbar();
        initDrawerMenu();
        prepareImageLoader();
        cat = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.id_category);

        // first drawer view
        onItemSelected(R.id.nav_all);
        actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_nav_all));

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toogleSearchView(searchItem.isVisible());
            }
        });

        Tools.cekConnection(getApplicationContext(), ((View)findViewById(R.id.frame_content)));

        // for system bar in lollipop
        Tools.systemBarLolipop(this);
    }

    private void initToolbar(){
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        Tools.setActionBarColor(this, actionBar);
    }

    private void initDrawerMenu(){
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                updateFavoritesCounter(navigationView, R.id.nav_favorites, db.getFavoritesSize());
                toogleSearchView(true);
                showInterstitial();
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                actionBar.setTitle(item.getTitle().toString());
                return onItemSelected(item.getItemId());
            }
        });

        // navigation header
        View nav_header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        nav_header_lyt = (RelativeLayout) nav_header.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_lyt);
        nav_header_lyt.setBackgroundColor(Tools.colorBrighter(sharedPref.getThemeColorInt()));
        (nav_header.findViewById(R.id.menu_nav_setting)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySetting.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        (nav_header.findViewById(R.id.menu_nav_map)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityMaps.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            doExitApp();
        }
    }

    private void toogleSearchView(boolean open){
        if(open){
            searchItem.setVisible(false);
            searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha);
            hideKeyboard();
        }else {
            searchItem.setVisible(true);
            searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha);
        }
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
        searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_toolbar_hint));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                try {
                    FragmentCategory.filterAdapter(s);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                return true;
            }
        });
        searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
        searchItem.setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySetting.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }else if(id == R.id.action_rate){
            Tools.rateAction(ActivityMain.this);
        }else if(id == R.id.action_about){
            Tools.aboutAction(ActivityMain.this);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onItemSelected(int id) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        switch (id) {
            //sub menu
            case R.id.nav_all:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, -1);
                break;
            // favorites
            case R.id.nav_favorites:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, -2);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_featured:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[18]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_tour:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[0]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_food:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[1]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_hotels:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[2]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_ent:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[3]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_sport:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[4]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_shop:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[5]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_transport:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[6]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_religion:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[7]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_public:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[8]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_money:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[9]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_unifor:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[10]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_work:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[11]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_bano:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[12]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_opticas:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[13]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_baile:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[14]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_joyeria:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[15]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_ninos:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[16]);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_spa:
                fragment = new FragmentCategory();
                bundle.putInt(FragmentCategory.TAG_CATEGORY, cat[17]);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            //initToolbar();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void hideKeyboard(){
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    private long exitTime = 0;
    public void doExitApp() {
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - exitTime) > 2000) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.press_again_exit_app, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void prepareImageLoader(){
        Tools.initImageLoader(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if(!imgloader.isInited()) Tools.initImageLoader(this);
        updateFavoritesCounter(navigationView, R.id.nav_favorites, db.getFavoritesSize());
        if(actionBar != null){
            Tools.setActionBarColor(this, actionBar);
            // for system bar in lollipop
            Tools.systemBarLolipop(this);
        }
        if(nav_header_lyt != null){
            nav_header_lyt.setBackgroundColor(Tools.colorBrighter(sharedPref.getThemeColorInt()));
        }
        super.onResume();
    }


    private void updateFavoritesCounter(NavigationView nav, @IdRes int itemId, int count) {
        TextView view = (TextView) nav.getMenu().findItem(itemId).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.counter);
        view.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }

    private void prepareAds(){
        // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        //prepare ads
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest2);
    }

    /** show ads */
    public void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready
        if (AppConfig.ENABLE_ADSENSE && mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }


    public static ActivityMain getInstance(){
        return activityMain;
    }

    public static void animateFab(final boolean hide) {
        FloatingActionButton f_ab = (FloatingActionButton)activityMain.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        int moveY = hide ? (2 * f_ab.getHeight()) : 0;
        f_ab.animate().translationY(moveY).setStartDelay(100).setDuration(400).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es una pared de codigo, podrias poner solamente el codigo relevante a la pregunta?

Comment: Bajo el supuesto de que todas las zonas tienen todas las categorías, deberias de hacer que la tabla de locales tenga una relación con las tablas de categorías y zonas. En java, en tu objeto local, tendrías dos atributos nuevos para categoría y zona. Ya montada esa relacion, es facil filtrar por consulta SQL para que solo te salgan los locales de una zona y categoría especifica